# How does types erasure help Clojure exist?

Tags: clojure, jvm, jvm-languages

How does JVM type erasure help Clojure?  Can Clojure exist without it?  What would happen if the JVM had reified types?  That is, how would Clojure change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clojure wouldn't change much at all.  Type erasure only applies to Java's type-parameters for generics.  All other types are available at runtime.

Browsing [Clojure's source](http://github.com/richhickey/clojure), it does not use generics much at all.  In the [runtime](http://github.com/richhickey/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/RT.java), it passes around `Object`s and does `instanceof` checks.  By treating everything as an `Object`, it has no need for generics, and thus, there are no type-parameters to be erased.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell Clojure does not use type erasure from the JVM, so i dont think much would change with out it.